# Neural network for multiple input and multi output (MIMO) systems

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I want to build a neural network for a multi input and multi output (MIMO) system described as:

```
y1(t)= f1( x1(t), x2(t),...xn(t))
y2(t)= f2( x1(t), x2(t),...xn(t))
.....
.....
ym(t)= fm( x1(t), x2(t),...xn(t))
```

The book I read describes examples of single input single output system, mostly for function approximation of the form  `y= f(t)`, where the neural network is trained for input t (independent variable) and output y. I am using matlab neural network toolbox and the solution to the scalar case can easily be done. However, how do I construct or solve the MIMO problem ? How to I transform or represent the input or outputs to solve the problem with the matlab built in functions?

Answer (score 1):

First a very simple example:

1. First you need to make a matrix for input data and another for output data.
   Here I am using a pre-set data from MATLAB. You should try to make the structure of your input output data like this:

   ```
   [InData, TarData] = engin_dataset;
   ```

   so here we have two inputs and two outputs (MIMO) 2 → 2
2. Now you should create the network. I have chosen the feed-forward network:

   ```
   net1 = newff(minmax(InData),[10,2],{'tansig','purelin'},'trainlm')
   ```

   Here I have defined the input data range, number of neurons in each layer (including output layer = 2), the type of functions and the type of the training algorithm.
3. Now you can train your network :

   ```
   net2 = train(net1,InData,TarData)
   ```

and here the code comes, from one of the examples generated automatically by MATLAB:

```
% load data
[inputs,targets] = engin_dataset;
%inputs = engineInputs;
%targets = engineTargets;

% Create a Fitting Network
hiddenLayerSize = 10;
net = fitnet(hiddenLayerSize);

% Setup Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

% Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);

% Test the Network
outputs = net(inputs);
errors = gsubtract(targets,outputs);
performance = perform(net,targets,outputs)

% View the Network
view(net)
```

Comment: check the question/answer in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672850/how-to-set-output-size-in-matlab-newff-method